# How to customize serialize JSON of custom object in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have a `MapResult` and `TestController` as below.

```java
// MapResult.java
public class MapResult(){
    // map saves the data I need
    private Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void prop(String name, Object value){
        map.put(name, value);
        return this;
    }
    // ... other methods and properties
}


// TestController.java

@GetMapping("/test")
MapResult test() {
   return new MapResult().prop("name", "AAA").prop("age", 20);
}
```

How can I get the response `/test` in format of `{"name":"AAA","age":20}`?

Comment: Is there a specific need because of which you've created wrapper class `MapResult`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [ResponseEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html). Instead of returning MapResult directly create a new ResponseEntity out of MapResult and make your controller return that response entity.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the TestModel which have Map as property

```
public class TestModel {
    private Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void prop(String name, Object value){
        map.put(name, value);
        return;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getProp(){
        return map;
    }
}
```

and call map from above class from controller like below

```
@RestController
public class DummyController {
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public Map<String, Object> test() {
        TestModel t = new TestModel();
        t.prop("name", "AAA");
        t.prop("age", 20);

        return t.getProp();
    }
}
```

Then it will give you result as {"name":"AAA","age":20} after calling /test